# 3 разных bxslider работали по одному контроллеру

Tags: slider, javascript

я использую bxslider, на страничке идет 3 слайдера подряд - один за другим.
Каждый слайдер генерит свои отдельный bx-controls , т.е. кнопки prev и next.
Как сделать так, чтобы были только одни контроллеры и по клику на них вращались сразу все 3 слайдера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все, спасибо. Все нашел сам =)

Сделал три слайдера как отдельные, вот так:

```
 var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
 var slider2 = $('.bxslider2').bxSlider();
 var slider3 = $('.bxslider3').bxSlider();
```

Дальше отключил контроллеры слайдера и сделал свои стрелочки следующий слайд и предыдущий:

```
 <p><a id="slider-next">Следующий слайд</a><br />
 <a id="slider-down">Предыдущий слайд</a></p>
```

И написал свои обработчики событий и вызовы методов перемотки:

```
$('body').on('click', '#slider-next', function(){
    slider.goToNextSlide();
    slider2.goToNextSlide();
    slider3.goToNextSlide();
    return false;
});

$('body').on('click', '#slider-down', function(){
    slider.goToPrevSlide();
    slider2.goToPrevSlide();
    slider3.goToPrevSlide();
    return false;
});
```